# Using perl to sort through PDB files

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I've been trying to get my Perl program to sort through a PDB database one file at a time. What I need is a program that reads a file, does a bit of pattern matching, and depending on the outcome, moves the file to an appropriate folder without changing the filename. So far, I've come up with this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Basename;

@files = <top8000/rands/*> ; 
$file = 0;
$count = 1; 
while ( open (FILE, $files[$file]) )
{
    while (  $FILEREAD = <FILE> ) 
    {
        if ( $FILEREAD =~ "pattern" ) 
        {
            $count++;        
        };
    };
    $string ="$files[$file]";
    $filename = fileparse($string);
    if ($count >=2 ) {
        rename ( $files[$file] , "top8000/randsort/$filename.txt" );
    };
    $count = 1;
    $file++;
};
```

I know I'm supposed to use `my` before the `$string` and `$filename` variables here, but my program doesn't run with it, and I don't really understand what it does. Apart from that, I cannot figure out what's wrong with my program. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you actually have the typos `file` and `count` (variables without dollar sign in front `$file`) or is that just a copy/paste issue?

Comment: When you say "without changing the filename", did you actually mean "and changing the filename by adding the extension '.txt'"? Its an important distinction in this case.

Comment: oh ... fixed those .. still nothing. 
The original file in this case is a .txt file. I meant without changing the filename , at all.

Comment: Add `or die "Cannot rename: $!"` to the end of your rename statement. It sure looks like you are trying to move a file that is still open for reading.

Comment: You know its not polite to go on a lunch break when someone is trying to help you out.

Comment: Oh ... sorry ... didn't have internet access for a day. Thanks a ton for the help! Not closing the file was the problem. Works like a charm now ... you're a lifesaver.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped, you should mark it as accepted. And no, the problem was not checking the return value of `rename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you seem to be complicating things for yourself. I would guess that your problem now is that you are trying to rename a file that is still open for reading. As a general rule, you should always check the return value of all file interactions, like this:

```
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Cannot open file: $!";
rename $old, $new or die "Cannot rename: $!";
```

Because generally speaking such errors should often be considered fatal.

Your program can be simplified considerably by using some built in functionality:

```
use strict;
use warnings;  # always use these two
use File::Copy qw(move);

@ARGV = <top8000/rands/*.txt> unless @ARGV;  # default args    
my $outdir = "top8000/randsort";

while (<>) {           # read through the files
    if (/pattern/) {   # check each line
        close ARGV;    # close the file handle
        move $ARGV, $outdir or die "Cannot move $ARGV: $!";
    }
}
```

As you can see, you do not need to specify a file name when using the `File::Copy` module: If the destination address is a folder, the old name is used.

We are using the diamond operator `<>`, which when used uses either the standard input STDIN file handle, or -- in our case -- opens and reads files given as arguments to the script in `@ARGV`. And because this is Perl, we can do what we want and just put in default arguments if there are none.

Because your count checked for 1 or more hits, that is effectively the same as just moving the file at the first match, so why not do that? Just make sure you close the file first! The file handle in this case is `ARGV`. This also skips ahead to the next file in `@ARGV`, which is very convenient for us. The file name is contained in `$ARGV`, and we do not need to manipulate it any further, so we no longer need the `File::Basename` module.

`File::Copy` is a core module in Perl 5, so no installation required.